# is there a string to map splitter in google collections

Tags: java, string, dictionary, guava

I am looking for the opposite of map joiner in google collections. is there something like this, and if not why?

EDIT:
here is an example how I wish it would be:

```
Map<String,String> myMap = Splitter.on(",").keyValueSeparator("=").split("k1=v1,k2=v2");
```

EDIT:
I opened a [request](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=467) and it was implemented. will be available in guava R10.

Comment: You mean to parse a String to a Map ? And please, add the guava tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there no such a feature in guava.
For me the reason is that the entry String can have many formats, so that you have to create your own "parser" for your own format.
An (ugly) alternative could be this one, if you can modify the format of your entry string:

```
final String toSplit = "k1=v1" + getProperty("line.separator") + "k2=v2";
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(toSplit.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));
Maps.fromProperties(properties);
```

Comment: but the problem of parsing was already targeted by the splitter

Comment: Yes, but the Splitter is not SplitterAndMapMaker. With your "keyValueSeparator", it's not a Splitter anymore.Anyway, you can post a request on http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list and wait for guavaers answers.

Comment: Just for a reference, [this was added to Guava v10](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=467&can=1&q=milestone%3DRelease10%20status%3DFixed&sort=id%20-owner&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a class `Maps2` that provides a method

```
Map<String, String> mapSequence(String)
```

It also provides two overloaded methods where you can change the delimiters that are used a) between keys and values (default: `=`) and b) between entries (default: `,`). Guava classes like `Splitter` and `Iterables` are used internally to do the work. The returned map is a `LinkedHashMap`, so entry order is preserved.

```
public final class Maps2{

    public static final String DEFAULT_ENTRY_DELIMITER = ",";
    public static final String DEFAULT_KEYVALUE_DELIMITER = "=";

    private Maps2(){}

    public static Map<String, String> mapSequence(final String sequence){
        return mapSequence(sequence, DEFAULT_KEYVALUE_DELIMITER);
    }

    public static Map<String, String> mapSequence(final String sequence,
        final String keyValueDelim){
        return mapSequence(sequence, keyValueDelim, DEFAULT_ENTRY_DELIMITER);
    }

    public static Map<String, String> mapSequence(final String sequence,
        final String keyValueDelim, final String entryDelim){

        final Splitter entrySplitter =    Splitter.on(entryDelim)
                                                  .trimResults();
        final Splitter keyValueSplitter = Splitter.on(keyValueDelim)
                                                  .trimResults();
        final Map<String, String> map = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        for(final String token : entrySplitter.split(sequence)){
            final String[] items =
                Iterables.newArray(
                    keyValueSplitter.split(token), String.class);
            if(items.length != 2){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                   "Map String not well-formed");
            }
            map.put(items[0], items[1]);
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

**Test code:**

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    // note the randomly spread whitespace in the test code,
    // also the last entry has no value.
    // using Splitter().trimResults() we can handle junk like that
    final Map<String, String> map = Maps2.mapSequence("k1=v1 ,k2=v2, k3 =");
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

**Output:**

> {k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=}

Comment: & @Peter Knego - your two solutions does not allow value with equal sign (e.g. "k1=v1=s ,k2=v2" ). instead of using a second splitter you should use String.split function with limit arg token.split(keyValueDelim,2);(BTW: I do not allow comma in value :) )

Comment: I disagree, that would lead to unpredictable and unreliable results (what if the = is in the key, not the value?). I think it's better to fail fast, and no: a simple function like this can't map very complex strings. Use JSON if you want more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite trivial to roll your own:

```
// assumes that input is properly formed e.g. "k1=v1,k2=v2"
public Map<String, String> toMap(String input) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] array = input.split(",");
    for (String str : array) {
        String[] pair = str.split("=");
        map.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure, you can use Guava:

```
String queryParamStr = "key1=value1&key2=value2";
Splitter.on('&').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator('=').split(queryParamStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in guava.

But [StringToMap](http://bitbucket.org/bubbles.way/stringtomap) can do this for you.